# Ставить ли кавычки: "зеленый коридор", "зеленое строительство", "зеленая архитектура"?

Tags: пунктуация, словосочетания

Нужны ли кавычки в словосочетаниях ***зеленый коридор, зеленое строительство, зеленая архитектура?*** Если нужны, то все словосочетание надо заключать в кавычки или только слово ***зеленый***?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зеленый коридор

(1) Коридор, стены которого окрашены в зеленый цвет.
(2) Коридор, образованный зелеными насаждениями.
(3) Форма контроля на таможне.
(4) Дорожка на таможне, по которой идут те, кто хочет возпользоваться (3).
(5) Любой беспрепятственный проход или проезд.
*По словам источника, Масхадову будет предоставлен «зеленый коридор» для выезда из Чечни в одну из зарубежных стран. [Масхадов уедет из Чечни. Переговоры Казанцева и Закаева уже начались (2001) // «Известия», 2001.11.01]*

(1) и (2) сомнений не вызывают - кавычки не нужны.
Для остальных случаев в Нацкорпусе можно найти примеры с кавычками ("зеленый коридор") и без. На мой взгляд, термин этот знаком и понятен всем, кавычки можно опускать, если контекст позволяет (смысл выражения не вызывает сомнений).

Зеленая архитектура

Термин однозначный и ставший привычным. Поэтому я бы писал его без кавычек. В отношении похожих терминов: *зеленая экономика, зеленая энергетика, Зеленая революция*, – Грамота советует кавычек не ставить. (http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=290679 и http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=266817). 
В Нацкорпусе встречается без кавычек и с первым словом в кавычках ("зеленая" архитектура).

Зеленое строительство

(1) Озеленение

*Наряду с этим строительством развивается быстрыми шагами зеленое строительство ― озеленение новых городов, колхозов, цехов. [Н. Базилевская. Собирайте семена цветов! // «Юный натуралист, 1940]*

*Груняхин заключил на год договор с трестом зеленого строительства, а так же с Мосмебелью и другими организациями. [А. П. Платонов. Счастливая Москва (1936)]*

(2) Вид строительства и эксплуатации зданий, воздействие которых на окружающую среду минимально ([Википедия](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE))

(1) сомнений не вызывают - кавычки не нужны.
Для (2) можно найти примеры без кавычек (Википедия) и с первым словом в кавычках ("зеленое" строительство).

*У России сейчас уникальная возможность для «зеленого» строительства. [Алеся Лонская, Роджер Бейли. О том, как спасти Москву // «Русский репортер», № 45 (223), 17 ноября 2011, 2011]*

На мой взгляд, термин этот знаком и понятен всем, кавычки можно опускать.